# Given 3 points and there distances from eachother find a fourth point equidistant to the 3.

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

**This question can also be asked: given a triangle, and its dimensions, whose vertices lie on the edge of a circle find the radius of the circle.**

I am not actually sure if there is enough information to solve this problem (I conjured it myself) but I have the strongest intuition that there is. It just makes perfect sense visually in my head that this should be answerable, but I have failed to formalize this intuition. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The title and the question describe two different problems. Finding the radius of the firm circle is east; finding its center is impossible (from the given information).

Comment: Sorry. I meant to write: finding the radius of the circumcircle is easy.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Triangles), the **diameter** of the **circumscribed** circle of a triangle can be found in terms of the length of its three sides, $a,b,c$ :

$$\frac{abc}{2\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}}$$

where $$s = \frac{a + b + c}{2}$$.

Comment: Better to summarize the relevant result, as the link might not work in the future.